# Heroku Django app can't start up -- 'No module named site'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django app to heroku, but I keep receiving an enigmatic 'ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named lukasSite' -- lukasSite is the name of the website I'm working on. It's also the name of my project folder, and app, though I have some other folders named 'community.'

I can't tell where this error is coming from, but I get it both when I try to run `heroku local web` and try to deploy my website to Heroku. Full error below:

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
21:33:09 web.1   |  [2017-10-19 21:33:09 -0500] [18983] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
21:33:09 web.1   |  [2017-10-19 21:33:09 -0500] [18983] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (18983)
21:33:09 web.1   |  [2017-10-19 21:33:09 -0500] [18983] [INFO] Using worker: sync
21:33:09 web.1   |  [2017-10-19 21:33:09 -0500] [18986] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18986
21:33:09 web.1   |  [2017-10-20 02:33:09 +0000] [18986] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
21:33:09 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
21:33:09 web.1   |      worker.init_process()
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
21:33:09 web.1   |      self.load_wsgi()
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
21:33:09 web.1   |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
21:33:09 web.1   |      self.callable = self.load()
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
21:33:09 web.1   |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
21:33:09 web.1   |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
21:33:09 web.1   |      __import__(module)
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/community/community/wsgi.py", line 28, in <module>
21:33:09 web.1   |      application = get_wsgi_application()
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
21:33:09 web.1   |      django.setup(set_prefix=False)
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
21:33:09 web.1   |      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
21:33:09 web.1   |      app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
21:33:09 web.1   |      module = import_module(entry)
21:33:09 web.1   |    File "/Users/lukasudstuen/softwareProjects/lukassite/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
21:33:09 web.1   |      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
21:33:09 web.1   |  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lukasSite'
21:33:09 web.1   |  [2017-10-20 02:33:09 +0000] [18986] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18986)
21:33:10 web.1   |  [2017-10-19 21:33:10 -0500] [18983] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
21:33:10 web.1   |  [2017-10-19 21:33:10 -0500] [18983] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
21:33:10 web.1   Exited with exit code 3
```

Things I've already tried:

- Renaming the project, and folders, to be the same case. (I'm working locally on a Mac, and deploying to Heroku, which has linux)
- Renaming all of the references throughout the project to be lower case as well
- Looking through my files to see anywhere lukasSite is defined ...
- Scouring the Heroku 'how-to-deploy' information, as well as forums.

Does anyone have any ideas of where I could start looking? I'm completely stumped as to where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another folder containing my Django project folder that was getting pushed up with my project. Turns out the folder structure must match the example Django project structure provided.

Comment: This was my problem as well. The root directory should house the main django apps/files.